# Choices separated by a comma

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**I'm new to discord.py**

So, I have this simple code that makes random choices, But currently it separates choices by space but i want it to be separated by comma so that it can make a random choice of sentences separated by a comma instead of every word after a space. How do i do that?

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def choose(ctx, *choices: str):
        async with ctx.channel.typing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await ctx.send("Hmm.. Let me think.")

        async with ctx.channel.typing():
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            await ctx.send(random.choice(choices))
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps split the string in your function: `choices = ' '.join(choices).split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
choices = ','.join(choices).split(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be the correct solution.
Its different from any previously given answer due to position of bracket.

```
choices = ','.join(choices.split(' '))
```

Comment: There is difference in position of bracket in my answer. Both work differently too.